# What (and where) are these points of reflection I saw from a flight?

Tags: usa, identify-this

Recently on a YUL-LAX flight (number AC797), I was sitting at one of the right side windows and saw these nine (may be unclear on image) *extremely* bright points of reflection.

[image]

**Easier to spot view** [**Here.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQvrf.jpgg)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQvrf.jpg]

I don't have an exact location, but the aircraft was over a vast sandy/rocky terrain so I presume that I was close to Los Angeles/California.

These points remained for an extended amount of time and I am certain that they were not ghosts/reflections off the aircraft's windows.

What did I manage to photograph? A solar farm? A military base? Tesla's famous Gigafactory One?

Comment: How long before you landed?

Comment: @MastaBaba An hour and half to two hours?

Answer (score 7):

[This article](http://qz.com/188109/pilots-complain-that-glare-from-ivanpah-the-worlds-biggest-solar-power-plant-is-blinding-them/) provides the possibility that it is [Ivanpah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivanpah_Solar_Power_Facility):

> Airplane pilots reported that they were blinded by the intense
> sunlight reflecting off some of the 340,000 mirrors at the Ivanpah
> Solar Electric Generating System on the California-Nevada border.
>
> ... He’s not alone. “Daily, during the late morning and early afternoon
> hours we get complaints from pilots of aircraft flying from the
> northeast to the southwest about the brightness of this solar farm

A search on [ASRS](http://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/search/database.html) for Ivanpah returns 5 reports, e.g.

> The Ivanpah Solar Power Plant glare caused cockpit illumination. The
> glare makes scanning for traffic impossible over approximately 40
> degrees of the horizon which is directly ahead of the aircraft

An alternative solar farm may be the [Topaz Solar farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topaz_Solar_Farm).

It's not clear from your timing or flight path which is the most likely of these two but I suspect a solar farm is the most likely option.

Answer (score 6):

Other answers suggesting a solar farm match well with your image.

Based on your estimates of 1.5 to 2 hours before arrival you were probably somewhere between the green lines shown on this image of the flight route.

[image]

[Wikipedia advises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_power_in_the_United_States) that

Colarado has:

Antonito Southeast 9,712 acres (865 MW - 1,557 MW)

De Tilla Gulch 1,064 acres (135 MW - 243 MW)

Fourmile East 2,882 acres (345 MW - 621 MW)
[here](https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/La+Jara,+CO+81140,+USA/@36.6861011,-108.454672,7z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x8716662df935c875:0x6e6645a851fb7de4!8m2!3d37.2750084!4d-105.960301?hl=en)

Los Mogotes East 4,734 acres (526 MW - 947 MW)
[here](https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/Los+Mogotes/@36.5126118,-96.974584,4.44z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x8716388f24561797:0xabf8768959e5fb83!8m2!3d37.0775109!4d-106.1722489?hl=en)

The most likely seem to be

Antonito Southesast Solar [here](https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/Antonito,+CO+81120,+USA/@33.5457517,-101.4984752,5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x8716450c89d99fcb:0x34f5344ec55b8bc9!8m2!3d37.079179!4d-106.0086329?hl=en)

but depending on how much the flight path varied, all 4 are possibilities.
(Or somewhere else :-) ).

Most of the station names do not correspond to a larger town but are a geographical location that may not show up on most maps. So the following two best guesses based on web searches are hopefully correct but ... .

[image]